# Scheduling spark job which inserts data in postgresdb in airflow env

Tags: postgresql, pyspark, airflow, batch-processing, spark-submit

I want to schedule spark write operation to postgres db. I have attached my code below. My airflow task instance triggers before hour. What can I do to make it run at exact an hour with only one task instance per dag run

```
df = spark.read \
.format("jdbc") \
.option("url", URL) \
.option("dbtable", "tagpool_with_tag_raw") \
.option("user", "tsdbadmin") \
.option("password", "cgqu5zy3i1") \
.option("driver", "org.postgresql.Driver") \
.load()

# Getting the current date and time
dt = datetime.datetime.now(timezone.utc)
utc_time = dt.replace(tzinfo=timezone.utc)
utc_timestamp = utc_time.timestamp()
epoch = round(utc_timestamp / 60) * 60
# epoch = epoch-3600
print("epoch ", epoch)

df.createOrReplaceTempView("tagpool_with_tag_raw")
x = spark.sql("""select *  from tagpool_with_tag_raw""")
x.show()
query = spark.sql("select *  from tagpool_with_tag_raw WHERE input_time = " + str(epoch))  # .format()

    # query = spark.sql("select CAST(input_time AS bigint), CAST(orig_time AS bigint) ,  from tagpool_with_tag_raw WHERE input_time = "+ epoch) #.format()
query.show()
# df.selectExpr(("SELECT * FROM public.tagpool_raw WHERE input_time<= %s".format(epoch)))
df.printSchema()

query.write \
    .format("jdbc") \
    .option("url", URL) \
    .option("dbtable", "tagpool_tag_raw") \
    .option("user", USER) \
    .option("password", PW) \
    .option("driver", DRIVER).save(mode='append')
```

My DAG  is as follows:

```
default_args = {
'owner': 'lns',
'depends_on_past': True,
"start_date": datetime(now.year, now.month, now.day),
'email_on_failure': True,
'email_on_retry': True,
'retries': 0}

with DAG(dag_id='kafka_stream',
     default_args=default_args,
     schedule_interval= '@hourly',
     max_active_runs=1,
     ) as dag:

SparkSubmitOperator(task_id='batch_ingestion',
                                    conn_id='spark_default',
                                    application=f'/usr/local/spark/app/demo.py',
                                    conf={"spark.master":spark_master},
                                    total_executor_cores=1,
                                    packages="org.apache.spark:spark-streaming-kafka-0-8_2.11:2.4.4",
                                    executor_cores=2,
                                    executor_memory='6g',
                                    name='data_processor',
                                    jars=postgres_driver_jar,
                                    driver_class_path=postgres_driver_jar,
```

Comment: Didnt qutie get 'make it run at exact an hour with only one task instance per dag run' you want to run this DAG every hour once ? https://crontab.guru/#0_*_*_*_* you have use @hourly or the link in you DAG to run every hour

Comment: @Rafa Yes, make it run at exact an hour with only one task instance per hour dag run,  I did '@hourly' but stil i can see 4 instances being created after first run

Comment: @Rafa I solved it by using catchup = False, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by using catchup = False,

```
DAG(dag_id='kafka_stream',
     default_args=default_args,
     schedule_interval= '@hourly',
     max_active_runs=1,
     catchup = False
     )
```